# How to set the path for keytab file in Windows Server, for spark submission to YARN

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, kerberos, spark-submit, keytab

I am struggling with this matter from a long time now, and I am in desperate search for help.

**Context**

I have a fat jar to be submitted by `spark-submit` to YARn resource manager.
YARN authentication is managed by Kerberos protocol, for which I have a valid principal and a keytab file. Keytab had been previously tested to be valid.

YARN resource manager, and the whole cluster, runs on Cloudera on Linux servers.
My application needs to be submitted from a Windows Server.

I have put my keytab file in C:\Kerberos\filename.

For enabling Spark to automatically create Kerberos ticket, I want to pass keytab and principal when submitting. I am doing that by putting these following configurations in `spark-defaults.conf` file:

- spark.yarn.keytab = C:\Kerberos\filename
- spark.yarn.principal = user@domain

**Issue**

Two things happen:

- in the situation I described, when submit starts I get a login successful message, but by the time the Spark context starts and goes to YARN, I get a `No FileSystem for scheme: C`, which makes me think it is interpreting `C` as prefix rather than root.
- if I try `file:///C/Kerberos/filename` I get immediately a file not found exception. This is caused by a check in `SparkSubmit.scala` (checked the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.2/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit.scala) for version 2.2 - the one I'm using), which is never going to work with a URI like `file:///`

How on earth am I supposed to specify the path for keytab file?
I can only guess this is somewhay dependent on Windows Server being the submitter

Comment: did you tried with relative part something like ../../Kerberos/filename

Comment: Did you try putting *C:\Kerberos\filename* in the Windows System PATH?

Comment: Really tricky to mix Kerberos conf (injected via JAAS config entries) and Windows paths... Try `C:/kkk/fff` with forward slashes (java libs switch automatically to the actual FS separator) or `C:\\kkk\\fff` with escapes.

Comment: And BTW relative paths for keytabs get messed in some JVM versions, whereas absolute paths always work (when using the correct syntax)

Comment: Thanks all. For now I have opted for relative paths, which solve the issue